# OrderClose is closing order OP_SELL above and OP_BUY bellow the OrderOpened?

Tags: mql4

I'm trying to create a dynamic Take Profit programatically. To do this I am using OrderClose() to close the order when the difference of pips are ready. The problem is that it is closing above the OP_SELL and bellow OP_BUY and I don't know why it happens.

how could I fix this ?

**Trying**

```
void executeTakeProfit(int mn, double points){   
  double _diffPips = 0;


  if(OrdersTotal() > 0){
      RefreshRates();

      for(int x = 0; x < OrdersTotal(); x++){
         if(OrderSelect(x, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)){
            if(OrderMagicNumber() == mn && OrderSymbol() == Symbol()){


               if(OrderType() == OP_BUY){
                  if(Ask > OrderOpenPrice()){
                     _diffPips = NormalizeDouble((Ask - OrderOpenPrice()) / Point, Digits);
                     if(_diffPips >= points){
                        if(!OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Bid, 0, clrNONE)){
                           Comment("Error Take Profit - Buy");
                        }   
                     }
                  }
               }//buy

               if(OrderType() == OP_SELL){
                  if(Bid < OrderOpenPrice()){
                     _diffPips = NormalizeDouble((OrderOpenPrice() - Bid) / Point, Digits);                     
                     if(_diffPips >= points){
                        if(!OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Ask, 0, clrNONE)){
                           Comment("Error Take Profit - Sell");
                        }               
                     }
                  }
               }//sell



            }//magic



         }//select
      }//for




  }


}//execute take profit
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When entering the market, you can buy (open `OP_BUY`) at `Ask`, sell at `Bid`. When exiting, the operation is opposite: if you have a buy trade, you can close it by selling (so execution is to be done at `Bid` price, for sell - at `Ask` price).
In order to skip this annoying logic, you can use `OrderClosePrice()` all the time.

So,

```
for(int x = OrdersTotal()-1; x>=0; x--){
     if(!OrderSelect(x, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) continue;
     if(OrderMagicNumber() != mn || OrderSymbol() != _Symbol)continue;
     RefreshRates();
     if(OrderType()==OP_BUY){
        if(OrderClosePrice()-OrderOpenPrice()>_Point/2.) {
          if(NormalizeDouble((OrderClosePrice()-OrderOpenPrice())/_Point,_Digits)>=points)//points is an external parameter here, that actually means ticks not points
            {
             TradeClose(OrderTicket());
            }
        }
     }//and same for sell, but of course it's easier to have same logic for buy and sell
 }


void TradeClose(const int ticketId){
   if(!OrderSelect(ticketId,SELECT_BY_TICKET))return;
   RefreshRates();
   //better to make several attempts to close the ticketId
   if(!OrderClose(ticketId, OrderLots(), OrderClosePrice()))
       Comment();
}
```

Comment: for OP_SELL is that `OrderOpenPrice()-OrderClosePrice() < _Point / 2` ?

Comment: yes. But as I told you, it seems much better to have same logic for both long and short (in order to support the code in one place only. For that, `int dir=OrderType()%2==OP_BUY?1:-1` and `dir*(OrderClosePrice()-OrderOpenPrice())` is used elsewhere

Comment: One more thing to add to the answer, it is better to use a decrementing `for` loop instead of the incrementing one, because the `OrdersTotal()` value decreases when an order is closed.

Comment: @TheLastStark, I agree with you and updated the answer with respect to your (valuable) contribution